# Linux Shell Script to change file mode

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am entirely new to shell scripts. I know how to change the mode for a single file.

But, I need to meet the following requirement and my operating system is red hat enterprise linux

1. To find all files in a directory which are having 640 mode and then change it to 644.

Like wise im having 10 directories where i need to recursively find all the files in all directories and change the mode to 644.

2. Later sending email with the file names whose status have been changed.

Expecting your kind assistance to complete this requirement.

Comment: Have you written any code yet?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian : I'm entirely new to shell scripting so i dont have any code.  Sorry

Comment: You should probably get a book or read some tutorials on the subject before asking questions here.  SO expects you to have some _basic understanding_ of the technologies you're asking about.

Comment: @Saibalu Then you should google for tutorials on shell scripting and come back when you have some code to show that isn't fully working.

Comment: A tutorial on shell scripting will almost certainly be useless in this context, guys, you need to know _what tool to use!_ That would be the `find` tool. Once the asker knows that, _then_ they can go off and write some code.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Thank you for your suggestion.  I will go through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some research points to get you going.

- The `find` command can be used to find files of varying properties under a given point.
- You can use it with `-type` to select specific file types (regular files, directories, etc).
- You can use it with `-maxdepth` to restrict how deep it will go down the tree.
- You can use it with `-perm` to select only files with specific permissions.
- You can use it with `-print` to output the filenames, including capturing them to a text file for later mailing (with a tool like `mailx`).
- You can use it with `-exec` to carry out arbitrary commands on each file matching the conditions.
- `chmod` is the command to change permissions.

For example, the following commands will find all regular files of the form `*.dat`, in the current directory (no subdirectories) and with permission `640`, then change all those permissions to `644`:

```
find . -type f -perm 640 -name '*.dat' -maxdepth 1 -exec chmod 644 {} ';'
```

All these options, and more, can be found in the manpage for `find` with the command:

```
man find
```

or by looking for some good explanations, such as the [GNU find documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html).

However, `find` is not a tool for the faint of heart, it will bite you at every opportunity. Expect to ask at least *another* ten questions here before you get what you need :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input now i have some basic idea of how to do it